# Linking 64bit app with 32bit lib in centos 5.6 64bit

Tags: c++

I want to build an application on Centos 5.6 64bit as a 64bit application and link it with a 32bit library.
How can i do this and what is the switches i need to pass to the gcc to compile and link.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.  A 64 bit application must link to 64 bit libraries.  If the library you must use is 32 bit, you must compile your application 32 bit as well.